# Multiple edits before peer-review

Tags: support, suggested-edits, review

If I edit someone elses question, and before it gets peer-reviewed I make another change (spotted something I missed). Will the two changes be merged into one for review or will they require separate reviews and result in separate revisions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as I've seen so far, editing within 5 minutes range still count as the same edit.

It won't be merged, it will replace the previous edit and keep the previous edit time stamp.